# How deploy Application Page - Missing WSP file

Tags: visual-studio, solution-deployment

I have made a project in VS 2010 and added an application page to the project. 
When i build the project i get no WSP file. There is also no items in feature . 
If i add a WebPart item, then i get a feature and the WSP file from build.

How can i create the WSP file without adding other features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. In Visual Studio 2010 Create a New Empty SharePoint Project
2. Right click the project - Add New Item - Application Page
3. From the menu - Build-> Build (No WSP)
4. From the menu - Build-> Package (WSP in BIN/Debug Folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.
You must insert the resource inside an existing feature through the wsp designer tool under visual studio 2010

Comment: I have no other features in my project, only the Application Page. The Application page is not available in any scope in the wsp designer tool.

Comment: So you need to create a feature if you want follow a correct way to deploy it